# Can a variable in one function can be used in another function in the same model using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code.... and my doubts along with the code 
See in the function `toltalRetailerComm($userId)` ... I am fetching the value of

> $shoppeId

and

> $storeId

and this same variable can be used in the next function `retailerDailyComm($userId, $fromDate, $toDate)` by using in this manner function `retailerDailyComm($shoppeId,$storeId, $fromDate, $toDate)`

```
function toltalRetailerComm($userId) {

    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_super_shoppe WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $shoppe_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_store WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $store_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($shoppe_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $shoppe_query->row();
        $shoppeId = $result->shoppe_id;

        $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$shoppeId'";
        //$sql = "SELECT commission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id='$shoppeId ' BETWEEN '03-5-2011' AND '05-5-2011'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        print_r($shoppeId);

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = $query->row();
            $commission = $result->commission;
            return $commission;
        }

    } else
        if ($store_query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $result = $store_query->row();
            $storeId = $result->shoppe_id;

            $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_store_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$storeId'";
            //$sql = "SELECT commission FROM atm_store_commission WHERE shoppe_id='$storeId ' BETWEEN '03-5-2011' AND '05-5-2011'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            print_r($storeId);
            if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                $result = $query->row();
                $commission = $result->commission;
                return $commission;
            }
        }
}
```

/*********************TOTAL RETAILER COMMISSION ENDS****************************************************/

/*********************TOTAL RETAILER START TO END DATE COMMISSION STARTS********************************/

```
function retailerDailyComm($userId, $fromDate, $toDate) {

    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_super_shoppe WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $shoppe_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_store WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $store_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($shoppe_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $shoppe_query->row();
        $shoppeId = $result->shoppe_id;

        $sql = "SELECT commission as retailDailyCommission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id='$shoppeId ' BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = $query->row();
            $retailDailyCommission = $result->retailDailyCommission;
            return $retailDailyCommission;

        } else
            if ($store_query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $result = $store_query->row();
                $storeId = $result->shoppe_id;

                $sql = "SELECT commission as retailDailyCommission FROM atm_store_commission WHERE shoppe_id='$storeId' BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                    $result = $query->row();
                    $retailDailyCommission = $result->retailDailyCommission;
                    return $retailDailyCommission;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: explained above.... can the $storedId and $shoppeId can be used in the next function without writing the same procedure twice...

Comment: Please answer a few questions, the correct answer might be according to the situation
1. Are these two functions defined in a single class?
2. OR Are these being called in sequence (in the same scope) e.g., in another function?

Comment: yup these two functions are defined in a single class...2... no they are not called in a sequence they are called in another function...

Comment: I see no way except to define `$shoppeId` and `$storeId` as variables inside the class. Now when should they be initialized (in constructor or they should be passed as arguments) is based on what is the name of this class, as in what is it responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

You're inside a class, change your variables and it should work.

```
$this->shoppeId
$this->storeId
```